# How to scrape the url from a redirect link?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the link from a page, I already get the `data-url` which is contained in a button and when that button is clicked a website loads `URL = something.com/api?call=XXXXXX&auth=XXX`.

Then goes to the real website `anotherweb.com`

So I thought if I request that `URL`, I may get to `anotherweb.com`, and it worked !

Code   :

```
import requests
import urllib.error , urllib.request , urllib.parse
#import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('https://nova.egybest.bid/movie/extraction-2020')

id = url.split('/')[2]



url = requests.get(url).text
api_urls = []

soup = BeautifulSoup( url ,'lxml' )
table_url = soup.find('table' , class_='dls_table btns full mgb')
all = table_url.find_all('a' , class_= 'nop btn g dl _open_window')
for link in all:
   api_url = link['data-url']
   api_urls.append(api_url)

#Query para [call , auth]
for req in api_urls :
    http = 'http://' + id
    #time.sleep(4)
    new_url = requests.get(http + req)
    #time.sleep(3)
    print(new_url.url)
```

After some time it didn't work , instead the program prints `id` (loads the main page)

is there is any way to get the actual url `anotherweb.com`

Never Mind : i just got banned

NOTE: `id` is the page domain `something.com`

Comment: your question isn't clear, please [edit] your question and include much details as you can in order to be able to understand your issue !

Comment: your question is still unclear, but seems am able to understand your target. if you used `allow_redirects= False` then you will get the primary url which means it's turn off the redirections. because `response.url` by default will give you the end `url` whenever website redirects where redirection is turned on by default

Comment: i want to get direct to that page , but using `requests.get(url)` goes to the home page .. can i post the code in pastbin or something to show you ?

Comment: you can post your code within your question. click [edit]

Comment: added code with the link , you can see that there are 5 buttons for 5 different links/resolutions for the movie , when u click a one , you're being redirected to the vids...com page , i want to scrape that url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212948/discussion-between--c-and-ahmedo).